# What is the difference between `#[cfg(test)]` and `#[cfg(feature = "test")]`?

Tags: rust

I would like to understand the difference between `#[cfg(test)]` and `#[cfg(feature = "test")]`, preferably demonstrated through examples.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`#[cfg(test)]` marks something to be compiled only when the `test` config option is enabled, while `#[cfg(feature = "test")]` marks something to be compiled only when the `feature = "test"` config option is enabled.

[When running `cargo test`, one of the things that happens is that `rustc` is passed the `--test` flag which (among other things) "enables the test cfg option".](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rustc/tests/index.html) This is usually used to conditionally compile the test module only when you want to run the tests.

[Features are something that cargo uses for general conditional compilation (and optional dependencies).](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/features.html)

Try running:

```rust
#[cfg(feature="test")]
mod fake_test {
    #[test]
    fn fake_test() {
        panic!("This function is NOT tested");
    }
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod test {
    #[test]
    fn test() {
        panic!("This function is tested");
    }
}
```

Output will be:

```
running 1 test
test test::test ... FAILED

failures:

---- test::test stdout ----
thread 'test::test' panicked at 'This function is tested', src/lib.rs:13:9
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace


failures:
    test::test

test result: FAILED. 0 passed; 1 failed; 0 ignored; 0 measured; 0 filtered out; finished in 0.00s
```

Which shows that the fake test module was not enabled.